# something not right in for loop PHP

Tags: php, loops

Can someone tell me why me second echo is producing -1 ? As far as I know the loop stops exectuing when it is $x>=0 ... so why is second echo saying -1 where is that come from lool:

```
for ($x=5; $x>=0;--$x) {
//echo inside loop
echo $x . "<br>";
}
//echo outside loop
echo $x;
```

this produces: 
5
4
3
2
1
0
-1   <----i am sure this line shouldn't be there, shouldn't it say 0 ?

Comment: everything is ok, when `$x` is 0, it passes statment then it's decreased by one `--$x` and check if can execute loop once more, but now `$x` is `-1` then leaves loop... it would be `0` if conditional statement is `$x > 0`

Comment: Did you check ... outside the loop? http://3v4l.org/kEkqQ

Comment: yeah it is outside the loop, after the curly braces

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's working as intended.

Comment: yeah you didn't copy the whole code or answer my question

Answer (score 0):

He cicle until $x >= 0. The "last" cicle $x is < 0 and so Exit from FOR.
For this reason $x is -1 out of the cicle FOR.

The -1 value is the reason why the FOR end.

Comment: thank you that makes sense now, just had me confused a little bit,

Comment: so echo returns the evaluated statement that was not executed in the loop $x>=-1 is false, so last loop to be executed produced result 0, so when you check current echo it is -1 ;p

Answer (score 0):

Because the loop decrements x beyond 0. That's when it knows to stop. It will never evaluate less than zero in the loop but after the the last iteration it is one less than the limit.

Comment: yeah i knew that it just hit me now lool so obvious

Answer (score 0):

my assumption in my question was wrong the loop does not stop executing when it is $x>=0, it stops executing when it is $x>=-1 which is evaluated false, this is what the echo outside the loop returns the value that was evaluated false when the loop stopped iteration